# How to check if web page built matches with Figma Design?

Tags: figma

Figma design is given and asked to build the page as per that design.

How will I be ensured that the page design is as per Figma?

Or in other words, How to see the differences in page and Figma design with a highlighting or error( example design not matching etc.) being shown on the page, if anything doesn't matches with Figma design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to automate comparing your Figma design VS the fully implemented webpage or web app screen.

As of the moment, there is no one-click automated way to do this.

A fallback is to simply do manual ocular QA inspection of pages. This works, because it's most likely that your Figma layer structure doesn't directly correlate to the HTML tags of the webpages, most especially if your webpages are generated by frameworks like React or Angular.

Answer (score -1):

[Plz check the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICLnn.png. you can see **inspect** section on the right side of the figma. it shows the properties of the selected item.]

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. How will I check if the webpage is as per figma design?